# Accepting calendar invites via Google API

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, icalendar

How do I accept a calendar invite using something like the Google Calendar API or the Google Gmail API?

Bonus points if you can point me how to do it in Ruby, but just a hint at which API I should be using would be more than fine.

Comment: You can use calendar API to accept calendar invite. In events.update, you can send the optional parameter value, attendees[].responseStatus to "accepted". Here are the links for documentation and code in ruby https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/update and http://baugues.com/google-calendar-api-oauth2-and-ruby-on-rails. Google documentation itself(in the above links) has code in ruby. please check.

Comment: Hello @SGC – thanks for the idea; I was thinking of something similar but I’m curious if it’s always possible to modify the event if you’re not the owner/do not have permission to do so. Do you know if you can?

Comment: Hi  @EdwardOcampo-Gooding , I am looking for the result of the same query..have you found the solution till now? because as what I think is that you have to query the attendees calendar events by authorizing him and then match the iCalUID of the events got with the iCalUID of the event which was generated while creating the event. I am not able to found any direct option of accepting the event as of now

Answer (score 2):

You should be using events patch.

First create an Event with just the information you want to change. In this case, this will be the single attendee (even if there are multiple attendees) whose response you want to modify (which should be the same as the user under which the call is made), and the corresponding response status ("accepted", "declined", "tentative").

Then you execute patch, passing in the event id and the sparse event created above.

An example in Java is at https://stackoverflow.com/a/41054893/80075